# Put the output of one PHP function into another in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a plugin that outputs data with a simple tag reference

```
<?php echo $property['building_brochure']; ?>
```

This outputs the reference number for an uploaded pdf which in this example is 352.

I want to return the actual link for this, the following works

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( 352 ); ?>
```

However, I want the combine these so on the single page template for the entry the relevant PDF is called i.e.

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( 'building_brochure' ); ?>
```

Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: `echo ep_get_attachment_url( $property['building_brochure'] );` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the function as input into the other function the way Spectre-d has shared in comments.
i.e

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $property['building_brochure'] ); ?>
```

However if you face issues,like not correct attachment_URL, then it could be Type issue i.e. first function might be outputting string and not integer as expected by attachment_url function in that case I recommend:

```
<?php 
       $pdf_id = (int)$property['building_brochure']; 
       echo wp_get_attachment_url( $pdf_id ); 
?>
```